# How would you simulate a click in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I've tried .click() and that obviously isn't it. How can you simulate a click and make the webpage function as if you clicked it?

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});

$( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );
```

More information in : [jQueryDocumentation](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("p").click();
        alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> paragraphp will be click when the page loads </p>
```